# Python program,assign_add, the result might be a little confusing

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

[image]

```
   b= tf.ones([3,3],dtype=tf.float32)
   c= tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3],mean=1,stddev=2,dtype=tf.float32),name="c")
   d=tf.assign_add(c,b)
   init_op= tf.global_variables_initializer()
   with tf.Session() as sess:
     sess.run(init_op)
     x,y,z= sess.run([c,b,d])
     print(x,"\n!!\n",y,"\n!!\n",z,"\n!!")
     print(sess.run(d))
```

the third array output result should be added  'b' and 'c', but the result did not print as expected. Can you help me? Many thanks.

**I expect the third Array output result should be the same as the fourth Array. I am confused at the third Array result.**

Comment: [Please don't post code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: as I understand it, your fourth Array is c+b - what would you expect?

Comment: The third output matrix should already be the same as the last one. That's what OP is wondering.

Comment: Although I do not have a satisfying answer as of yet, it is interesting to note that `d = tf.add(c,b)` will return the correct result, but `tf.assign(c,c+b)` will return the same as the above.
It seems that, according to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign_add) it should already return the updated value, though.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like contrary to how I understand [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign_add) on `assign_add`, this op might actually return the value of the variable *before* the adding is done, not after.

So in this example `c` is the variable with value `[[4.723362, ...]]`. In the first `sess.run`, you are printing `c` which has the pre-assign_add value since the update is done after, `b` which looks as expected and `d` which *also* returns the pre-assign_add value because that's presumably how the op works.
After this, `c` is updated to now contain values `[[5.723362, ...]]`. Now you run `d` (the `assign_add` op) again, which updates `c` but once again returns the *pre-update* value, which is `[[5.723362, ...]]`.

In conclusion, if we accept that the return value of `tf.assign_add` is the variable *before* adding, *and* that running `c` along with `d` in the first "parallel" run call will return `c` before doing the update, this makes sense. You could verify this by adding a `sess.run(c)` at the very end, which should return `[[6.723362,...]`.